# The font is ligher on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: html, mobile, css

I have this class on some of my texts `.description {font-weight: lighter;font-size: 22px; }`

But the `font-weight` attribute works on desktop but not on mobile, why is that?

When I scale chrome on my desktop to mobile size everything works fine, and the text is as light as it should be, but on mobile its not.

Comment: You might want to give information about the browsers you are using, both on mobile and desktop.

Comment: It's both chrome. It doesn't recognize font-weight on mobile, because I tried to set 900, that is gigantic, and on desktop works, but not on mobile. On mobile it stays just the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's working. The problem is that when you resize it to mobile it may seem as you have a bigger font. You may want to use responsive design so when the screen size is lower your font weight gets lower.

```
.description {
font-weight: 500;font-size: 22px; 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        font-weight: 300;font-size: 22px; 
    }
}
```

Or something like that. You can also set the font size lower and it may appear that your font weigth is lower too.

Comment: AHAHA no, I'm not blind yet. If I say it's not working, it's just not. But thanks for the attempt, my question wasn't about media querying the font (thing that I've done). It's just that on mobile the font is not light.

Comment: Oh i see. i think i didnt catch your problem the first time. try using google fonts if you are not using them maybe that could solve it. Sorry for not being able to answer.